# Best way to pass string to function?

Tags: php, string, function

What's the best way from security perspective to pass string to a function. I know I can use globals, session and in function string. Like function test($string). What's the best approach ? If any one knows please let me know.

I'm trying to write something like this for example:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/';

function test() {
  echo $url;
}
```

But if possible not using globals or in function strings. As described above.

Perhaps I could use define and defined?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Where does the string come from? How about `function test($url) { echo $url; }`?

Comment: @ codaddict, thanks for editing my post I was blind and did not see that code button.

Comment: @ Pekka, I figured it out buddy. I'm using define now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys, I used define. Here is example:

```
define('URL', 'http://domain.com/');

function test() {
  echo URL;
}
```

But if you any one else knows other ways, please reply.

Comment: Just did something like this define('XML', simple_xml_load('file.xml'));  did not work lol That would be nice do.

Comment: the normal way of passing a string to a function is using a parameter. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I think if you are asking *purely* from a security perspective, I'd say that using global variables to pass data to functions is best.

"Woah! Are you *mental*?" I hear you ask?

It's like the idea of abolishing seatbelts, and instead fixing a sharp, 6 inch spike onto all steering wheels instead. That would change your driving behaviour, no? You'd become the world's safest driver overnight!

So, if you forced yourself to use globals as parameters, you'd make sure your function did as much security checking on that data as possible, as you couldn't be sure your caller had taken care of it.

Of course, like the steering wheel spike, this is an utterly ridiculous suggestion. **In the real world, you use function parameters wherever possible**: easier to test, easier to read, allows recursive calls, etc... A more OO approach might be to use a class which takes the raw data in its constructor, and puts validated data into its member variables for other class methods to use.

Let the downvotes commence :)

Comment: I thought that globals is more un-secure :) Is using define good enough for security ?

Comment: I was being tongue-in-cheek, the question is a little silly. It doesn't matter what technique you use, you still have to sanity check the data.

Comment: @ Paul Dixon, I disagree :-) Yes, you need to check data always which I do. But there is better approaches.

Comment: But you pose your question from a *security* perspective, and there's little to distinguish the various techniques on those grounds. Using constants, as you suggest, doesn't really provide a parameter passing mechanism as it is invariant (or should be!)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is another answer I just figured out, which is good enough for me.

```
define('XML', 'file.xml');
```

then in function do soemthing like this

```
function test()
  $xml = simplexml_load_file(XML);
}
```

This way at least I don't need to change "file.xml" name if I need to in every function :-)

Comment: Why do you have multiple functions all reading the same file? One function is quite enough, if you need the xml in multiple places, then call that function and use the result - no need to keep the name of the file in some constant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo use $GLOBALS array
`function test() {
  echo $GLOBALS['url'];
}`

or

`function test() {
  global $url;
  echo $url;
}`